# What practical confidentiality protections can BSA offer to software piracy whistleblowers?

Tags: copyright, data-protection, discovery, secret, confidentiality

[This question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/37252/is-it-illegal-to-infringe-copyright-if-your-boss-or-your-client-ordered-you-to-d) refers to a [form](https://reporting.bsa.org/r/report/add.aspx#faqSection) for reporting software piracy.  That page has an FAQ question:

> **If I report software piracy to the BSA, will my name be kept confidential?**
>   Your name will never be revealed unless required by law. We take all appropriate measures to ensure your confidentiality at all times.

The top of the form says "Your report is confidential."

In most jurisdictions, wouldn't the party accused of violating copyright be entitled to get that information, "required by law" under a discovery process?

For purposes of this question, assume it's a well-founded valid report that BSA does not dismiss.

For clarity purposes from the link above:

> WHAT IS BSA | THE SOFTWARE ALLIANCE?
>
> BSA | The Software Alliance (BSA) is the leading advocate for the
>   global software industry. Its members are among the world's most
>   innovative companies, creating software solutions that spark the
>   economy and improve modern life.
>
> With headquarters in Washington, DC, and operations in more than 60
>   countries, BSA pioneers compliance programs that promote legal
>   software use and advocates for public policies that foster technology
>   innovation and drive growth in the digital economy.

Comment: It's worth noting that the vast majority of BSA cases never get to accusations through the government court process. A well-founded valid report that BSA does not dismiss is going to (in almost all cases) end through some negotiations between BSA and the violator - or, possibly, with a court case after a BSA-ordered audit (often permitted by some licence agreement terms; so no need to involve court discovery to enforce it) *if that audit* gets some evidence. So they're not really lying as it *is* generally going to stay confidential.

Answer (score 2):

> In most jurisdictions, wouldn't the party accused of violating
>   copyright be entitled to get that information, "required by law" under
>   a discovery process?

It depends. Sometimes a tip would allow BSA to independently develop evidence of infringement that wouldn't require naming you as a witness, other times the knowledge of a witness might be relevant to proving a case. In the later case, BSA would not generally be able to keep an informant's identity secret in the face of court ordered disclosure.

An example of the first case would be providing a YouTube url to BSA which it then investigated and brought suit upon. An example of the second case might be a report of a live concert at which infringing material was used, where the advertising didn't mention the use of the work when a concert recording wasn't released by a third-party.